# How to fix discord bot sending multiple responses?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So you are supposed type !apply that is the command it is supposed to send author.id a private messagein there inbox and ask it a list of specific questions. I'm running into a issue where it is sending multiple questions to the user at the same time. I'm not that knowledgeable in discord.js so please forgive me if it is not structured well. This is an application bot if you are curious.

```
Running into my command prompt sending this 
Apply begin for authorId 358036749055819779
Apply begin for authorId 358036749055819779
Apply begin for authorId 358036749055819779
```

````
const Discord = require("discord.js");
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  message.delete({ timeout: 10000 });




  let userApplications = {}
    bot.on("message", function(message) { ///NEED T


  if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

  let authorId = message.author.id;


      console.log(`Apply begin for authorId ${authorId}`)= { "step" : 1};
      // User is not already in a registration process
      if (!(authorId in userApplications)) {
          userApplications[authorId] = { "step" : 1}

          message.author.send("```We need to ask some questions so  we can know a litte bit about yourself```");
          message.author.send("```What is your light level and the total amount of hours you have played destiny?``` https://wastedondestiny.com/");
      }

  else {

      if (message.channel.type === "dm" && authorId in userApplications) {
          let authorApplication = userApplications[authorId];

          if (authorApplication.step == 1 ) {
              authorApplication.answer1 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```Whats is your timezone?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 2) {
              authorApplication.answer2 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```How many days of the week do you play destiny?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 3) {
              authorApplication.answer3 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```What raids have you completed and how many times?``` https://raid.report/");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 4) {
              authorApplication.answer4 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```Do you belive in helping others even if you get nothing in return?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 5) {
              authorApplication.answer5 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```What is your reason for wanting to join FearTheWise?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 6) {
              authorApplication.answer6 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```What is your PSN?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 7) {
              authorApplication.answer7 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```Are you over 18 years of age?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 8) {
              authorApplication.answer8 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```Thanks for your registration. Type !apply to register again```");


              let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('<:fearthewise:637422744610537492>-------Clan Application-------<:fearthewise:637422744610537492>')
                .setColor('#ffd700')
                .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/eCYcee3.png")
                .addFields({name:'What is your light level and the total amount of hours you have played destiny? https://wastedondestiny.com/ ', value: `${authorApplication.answer1}`},)

                .addFields({name: 'Whats is your timezone? ', value: `${authorApplication.answer2}`},)

                .addFields({name: 'How many days of the week do you play destiny?', value: `${authorApplication.answer3}`},)

                .addFields({name: 'What raids have you completed and how many times? https://raid.report/', value: `${authorApplication.answer4}`},)

                .addFields({name: 'Do you belive in helping others even if you get nothing in return?', value: `${authorApplication.answer5}`},)

                .addFields({name: 'What is your reason for wanting to join FearTheWise?', value: `${authorApplication.answer6}`},)

                .addFields({name: 'What is your PSN?', value: `${authorApplication.answer7}`},)

                .addFields({name: 'Are you over 18 years of age?', value: `${authorApplication.answer8}`},)

                .addField("Applicant Username", `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)

                .setFooter("Bot created by James (Rock)₇₇₇",);





              //before deleting, you can send the answers to a specific channel by ID
              bot.channels.cache.get("616852008837709844")









            .send(embed).then(async msg => {
                await msg.react('');
                await msg.react('');
                await msg.react('');
                await msg.react('️');

                const threshold = 6;

    async function stop(result) {
      collector.stop();

      const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(msg.embeds[0]);

      newEmbed.title = newEmbed.title + ' [CLOSED]';
      newEmbed.fields[0] = { name: 'Status', value: 'Voting is now closed.\n' + result };
      newEmbed.setThumbnail('attachment://thumbnail.png');
      await msg.edit(newEmbed);

      msg.reactions.removeAll();
    }

    async function update() {
      const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(embed);

      const userYes = (votes[''].size === 0)? '-' : [...votes['']];
      const userNo = (votes[''].size === 0)? '-' : [...votes['']];
      const userUnsure = (votes[''].size === 0)? '-' : [...votes['']];

      newEmbed.addFields(
        { name: `Votes Yes (${votes[''].size}/${threshold})`, value: userYes, inline: true },
        { name: `Votes No (${votes[''].size}/${threshold})`, value: userNo, inline: true },
        { name: 'Vote unsure', value: userUnsure, inline: true }
      );

      await msg.edit(newEmbed);

      if (votes[''].size >= threshold) {
        await stop('This answer is good enough to get accepted and an upvote.');
        // do something
      } else if (votes[''].size >= threshold) {
        await stop('This answer is not good enough to get accepted and an upvote.');
        // do something
      }
    }

    const votes = {
      '': new Set(),
      '': new Set(),
      '': new Set(),
      '️': new Set()
    };

    update();

    const collector = msg.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => !user.bot , { dispose: true });

    collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
      if (['', '', '', '️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name)) {
        const userReactions = msg.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(user.id));

        for (const userReaction of userReactions.values()) {
          if (userReaction.emoji.name !== reaction.emoji.name || reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
            userReaction.users.remove(user.id);
            votes[userReaction.emoji.name].delete(user);
          }
        }

        votes[reaction.emoji.name].add(user);
      } else {
        reaction.remove();
      }

      update();
    });

    collector.on('remove', (reaction, user) => {
      votes[reaction.emoji.name].delete(user);

      update();
    });
  });


              delete userApplications[authorId];
          }
      }
  }
});


}


module.exports.help = {
    name: "apply"
}
````

Answer (score 0):

Try [changing your bot token](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Your bot might be running multiple times and all instances are responding. If this still happens after changing the token, try using client.destroy(), or cmd+Z in your terminal (killing the script).

If none of that helps, just restart your computer.